# Deploy a laravel app on a shared hosting (Ionos 1&1)

Tags: laravel, ionos

First thing: I'm trying to connect the Ionos db on my project, I've insert in .env file all correct data but it return: "unknown host".

In my Ionos control panel I can't upload the project folder, I can just upload single files, I don't have idea, I don't now where put my hands.
Any suggestion?

I'm not asking you if is a good idea deploy a laravel app on an ionos domain, so please don't judge it.

Comment: I, personally, do not know Ionos at all. If you get `unknown host` then it either means you did not put the right domain/ip, or that domain/ip is inside a VPN/VPC and your code is not inside that VPN/VPC, so the host cannot be resolved. Hard to say if we don't have any documentation about Ionos.

Comment: is "unknown host" error which your datbase of domain ? , if it with domain , have you try to create index.php or index.html file in root directory and try to access it

Comment: Go step-by-step. Right now you have 2 problems: 1) uploading a project, 2) connecting to a database. Upload project first. What is not working? Show screenshot of the panel without sensitive information. Next, your .env file. What is url of your database? Show in .env file without sensitive information, change username password to something like 'root'

Answer (score 0):

First: You need the hostname of the DB that you created in Ionos. Then replace the DB_HOST in the Laravel project (.env file). Also recheck the DB_DATABASE, DB_USERNAME, and DB_PASSWORD.

Secondly: You can use FileZilla for uploading your project on Ionos. You can also get help from this [You can get additional detail here](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20host%20laravel%20project%20on%20ioinos&sca_esv=556349551&sxsrf=AB5stBiGKWYDC572NTBDMqTPb7neC0sUzw%3A1691864775792&ei=x87XZMb-L62GhbIPo8e70AM&ved=0ahUKEwiG_t-339eAAxUtQ0EAHaPjDjoQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=how%20to%20host%20laravel%20project%20on%20ioinos&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiJWhvdyB0byBob3N0IGxhcmF2ZWwgcHJvamVjdCBvbiBpb2lub3MyBxAhGKABGApI_iJQ2BFYhCBwAXgBkAEAmAFxoAGjA6oBAzIuMrgBA8gBAPgBAcICChAAGEcY1gQYsAPCAgQQIxgnwgIGEAAYFhgewgIIEAAYigUYhgPCAgUQIRigAeIDBBgAIEGIBgGQBgg&sclient=gws-wiz-serp#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:1ac0b3aa,vid:Qqp9qPgULEA),

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).